# Crazy blue video issues/artifacts on export

Tags: render

I am a super Premiere rookie, but I have never seen anything like this.

[image]

Here are my export settings.

[image]

[image]

The source footage looks nothing like this. I don't even know where to start looking at what could be causing this.

Comment: Hi Josh! When you scroll through the timeline, the artifacts do not appear, correct? Only on export? 

Perhaps a screengrab of your timeline would help us in our analysis of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your export settings are really what your camera films. Are you filming interlaced? Your settings suggest so, since it's rendering the upper field first, however, it could be that your camera films progressive. You can check whether your system records 25i or 25p for example. Also, is the pixel aspect ratio (par) really anamorphic (1,33)? Meaning, did you use a very stretching lense which costs about 10k dollars? If not, set the pixel aspect ratio to square (1).